# How to search for comma delimited string Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to search by column which contains comma delimeted string in Oracle APEX using Popup LOV.

I tried with `instr(column, :PX_ITEM) > 0` and it works only when I search for one value from column.

For `:PX_ITEM` I split string into rows.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question-- an example of the data in the column, the data in your bind variable, and the expected output would help.  Storing a comma-delimited list in a database column is a bad idea that violates basic normalization so any answer would likely start by fixing the data model.  If you can't fix the data model, my guess is that you want to parse the data in both the column and the local variable into collections (possibly using the `apex_util.comma_to_table` function) and then use an appropriate collection method.  But it's hard to say beyond that.

Comment: @JustinCave thanks for suggestions, currently I can't change data model, item is already split in rows, I want to get all rows that contain selected values :)